# Performance of view (as a table alias) over a table

Tags: sql-server-2005

Using a view to encapsulate a table whose name changes yearly (tablename_year) called "vw_Tablename_Current" so I don't have to change any procs that use the table to reflect the new table name, just the view.

This is temporary until I'm able to make deeper model changes. Is there any performance hit on wrapping a single table in a view like this?

Sql Server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a synonym as well which is cleaner

```
   CREATE SYNONYM tablename FOR tablename_year;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no performance difference if the view is essentially a `SELECT * FROM table`